# ANTLR: prevent "// Generated from <file name>"

Tags: antlr, antlr4

How to tell the ANTLR tool, e.g. by an VM option, not to create the first comment line in the Java files containing

```
// Generated from <file name>
```

The reason is that the absolute file name is written there and this creates unnecessary changes on different machines (we store the generated Java files in the repository, because why we should regenerate them always if they only change very seldom).

Comment: Generated files can be left out of source control.

Comment: But this would mean to regenerate the source files for every build. This makes sense for source files that often change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to tell the ANTLR tool, e.g. by an VM option, not to create the first comment line in the Java files

There is no way to exclude this.

Comment: For what it is worth, this kills Gradle task caching for any tasks using `org.antlr.v4.Tool`

Answer (score 0):

Alternative answer:
Create a build script that calls `antlr` to generate the AST and target files, and then modify this files with whatever scripting language you feel comfortable with.
It's not hard, the comment you mention is the first line and can be matched easily with a regular expression.